# Laravel 6.0 Braintree: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Braintree\Gateway' not found

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce, payment, braintree

I'm trying to integrate Braintree into my website. So far, not going well. This is the error I get when calling `CheckoutController::checkout()`:

`Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Braintree\Gateway' not found`

CheckoutController.php:

```
class CheckoutController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $gateway = new Braintree\Gateway([
            'environment' => config('services.braintree.environment'),
            'merchantId' => config('services.braintree.merchantId'),
            'publicKey' => config('services.braintree.publicKey'),
            'privateKey' => config('services.braintree.privateKey')
        ]);
```

.env:

```
BT_ENVIRONMENT=*********
BT_MERCHANT_ID=*********
BT_PUBLIC_KEY=*********
BT_PRIVATE_KEY=*********
```

services.php:

```
'braintree' => [
        'environment' => env('BT_ENVIRONMENT', 'sandbox'),
        'merchantId' => env('BT_MERCHANT_ID'),
        'publicKey' => env('BT_PUBLIC_KEY'),
        'privateKey' => env('BT_PRIVATE_KEY'),
    ],
```

Everything seems to be in order. I'm not sure why I get this error. What's wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess you are not using the good `Use Braintree;` path. Or try to reload composer : `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Thanks! That's all I needed. I just included ```use Braintree``` in my ```CheckoutController.php```.